# Regex to allow numbers and only one hyphen in the middle

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to allow numbers and only one hypen in the middle (cannot be at start or at the end)
say pattern: `02-04` , `02`are acceptable but 
pattern: `--` or `-` or `-02` or `04-` or `02-04-06` are unacceptable

I tried something like this but this would allow - at the beginning and also allow multiple -

```
'/^[0-9 \-]+$/'
```

I am not that good with regex so a little explanation would be real helpful.

> **EDIT:** Sorry to bug you again with this but I need the numbers to be of only 2 digits (123-346) should be considered invalid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^\d{1,2}(-\d{1,2})?$/
```

One or two digits, followed by, optionally, ( a hyphen followed by one or two digits)

Comment: Same answer as mine, but you beat me to it. So I added an explanation, upvoted, and deleted my own.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again with this but I need the numbers to be of only 2 digits (123-346) should be considered invalid.

Comment: 2 digits exactly? Or 1-2 digits? `\d[2]` or `\d\d` matches two digits. `\d[1-2]` or `\d\d?` matches 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: I updated the unswer so it only support one or two digits ({1,2} instead of +) (and thank you @slim)

Comment: @Yasmat and you spotted my [] vs {} fail :)

Answer (score 5):

Fairly easy:

```
^\d+(-\d+)?$
```

At least one (`+`) digit (`\d`), followed by an optional group containing a hyphen-minus (`-`), followed by at least one digit again.

Comment: but this would render `02` invalid, as a hyphen is required by your expression

Comment: Ah, sorry; overlooked the part that said that the hyphen-minus is optional. Fixed now. That requirement is a bit hard to see in the question, admittedly, as every verbal explanation of the pattern sounds like the hyphen-minus is required.

Answer (score 2):

For strings containing only that pattern the following should work

```
^(\d{2}-)?\d{2}$
```

A group of 2 digits followed by minus ending with a group of 2 digits without minus.